# Codenameone - IOS debug build getting failed

Tags: ios, build, codenameone

IOS Builds are failing since yesterday.Please advise. My IOS Development certificate is due for renewal on June 22nd. Is this issue something to do with it. This doesn't happen for Android Build.

ProcessInfoPlistFile build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/Info.plist Main-src/Main-Info.plist
cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/Main-src/Main-Info.plist -genpkginfo /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -additionalcontentfile /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/CodenameOne_GLViewController-PartialInfo.plist -additionalcontentfile /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/MainWindow-PartialInfo.plist -additionalcontentfile /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/Info.plist

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Script-FBB5AA14B5490680E4F090B8.sh
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    /bin/sh -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Script-FBB5AA14B5490680E4F090B8.sh
mkdir -p /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Main.app/Frameworks

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ Pods\ Resources build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Script-08D36CA0EB140342EBF71811.sh
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    /bin/sh -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Script-08D36CA0EB140342EBF71811.sh
building file list ... done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
building file list ... done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

Strip build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/Main
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/Main

SetOwnerAndGroup administrator:staff build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH administrator:staff /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app

SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /bin/chmod -RH u+w,go-w,a+rX /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app

ProcessProductPackaging /Users/administrator/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/442f896e-80bf-4914-9112-6f528cb22994.mobileprovision build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/embedded.mobileprovision
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /Users/administrator/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/442f896e-80bf-4914-9112-6f528cb22994.mobileprovision -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Touch build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app

ProcessProductPackaging /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/Entitlements9151643719498836432.plist build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main.app.xcent
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/Entitlements9151643719498836432.plist -entitlements -format xml -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main.app.xcent

CodeSign build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build9030811877552061486xxx/dist
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Chris Lace"
Provisioning Profile: "IOS_DEVELOPMENT Profile"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign   --entitlements /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main.app.xcent --timestamp=none /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app
(1 failure)
Process return code is 65
Failed xcodebuild step

Comment: How did you generate the certificate? Does your project path have any spaces or non-ascii characters within it? Did you modify provisioning in any way after generating the certificate? In Codename One Settings does the app ID match the value you see in itunes (the prefix characters)?

Comment: There used to be space in the project name and did worked before without any issue and deployed application in app store. Now my certificate got expired. when I tried to regenerate the certificate using the codenameone certificate wizard, it popped error saying path contains space. So I went and deleted the space in the project name and corrected Build.xml and codenameone_settings.properties without space manually. Now when I give the build I see this message.

Comment: When I tried to connect itunesconnect through codenameone wizard it failed with error "Failed to save token". I have updated AppID in apple itunes connect without space as well to match it. Please advise

Comment: The certificate wizard should work now, we had some downtime https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html

Comment: Thank You Shai. IT started working now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I've had iOS builds fail when you have an incorrect or relative path to the cert file rather than an absolute one. This doesn't seem to be the case though since you are getting a CodeSign error. Have you updated Xcode recently or changed anything in the .properties file?

Comment: I'm using codenameone certificate wizard to generate cert and provisional profile.